# For Canada eTA application, do i just write my first and last names in the signature field?

Tags: canada, eta

When applying for eTA, the signature part says to sign, enter your name as it appears on your passport. Does that mean I just write my full name and not actually my signature? Also do I have to do it in capitals?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. There is a [help document](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/eta/english.pdf) available to guide you through the eTA application process (accessible in various languages from [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/facts.html)). On page 19 of the english document, it clarifies that you should enter **the full name**, not just an abbreviated signature you would sign with pen and paper.

I am not sure whether capitalization is actually relevant, but for what it's worth, I did use capital letters only (because that is how it actually appears in the passport) and it seemed to be ok.